# Worker - Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'terminate')

Tags: javascript, worker

I have a simple worker that is communicating with main thread to update a progress bar. When is done it is sending a "done" message. 99% of the time there is no problem, but from time to time I got this error `Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'terminate')`. In the worker there is no `close()` method, so worker remain active forever. Why some browsers throw this error despite the fact that `myWorker` cannot be undefined when `myWorker.terminate();` is run?

```
        if (typeof(Worker) !== "undefined") {
            // Yes! Web worker support!
            myWorker = new Worker("/js/myworker.js");
            myWorker.onmessage = function(event){
                //console.log(event.data)
                if(event.data.work == "working"){
                    // update progress bar
                }else if(event.data.work == "done"){
                    // update progress bar 100%
                    myWorker.terminate();
                    myWorker = undefined;
                }
            }; 
            myWorker.postMessage("some things to do");
        }
```

Comment: Does this code run in a loop? I don't see you ever declare the `myWorker` variable